# summarise() - calculating percentages and counts of factor

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, summary

I'm trying to use summarise() from the plyr-packge to calculate percentages of occurences of each level in a factor. EDIT: The Puromycin data is in the base R installation

**My data look like this:**

```
library(plyr)
data.p <- as.data.frame(Puromycin[,3])
names(data.p) <- "Treat.group"
```

**I've done this:**

```
    summarise(  data.p, "Frequencies"= count(data.p), 
"Percent" = count(data.p)/ sum(count(data.p)[2] ))
```

**And got this:**

```
  Frequencies.Treat.group Frequencies.freq Percent.Treat.group Percent.freq
1                 treated               12                  NA    0.5217391
2               untreated               11                  NA    0.4782609
```

But I don't want the 3. column to be generated. It is unnecessary, and only shows NA.

**How do I write the code so I don't get that NA column?**

Any pointers are appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error was coming from:

```
count(data.p)/ sum(count(data.p)[2] )
```

If you look at the numerator, we get:

```
R> count(data.p)
  Treat.group freq
1     treated   12
2   untreated   11
```

So the warning occurred because you were dividing the first column by a number, i.e. `treated/12`, which gives `NA`. To avoid this, just select the second column of `count(data.p)`:

```
summarise(data.p, 
             "Frequencies"= count(data.p), 
             "Percent" = count(data.p)[,2]/ sum(count(data.p)[2]))
```